# Using UIImages from Photo Library

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I have an issue with pictures that I get from the photo library on iOS.

I'm using a code that uses UIImages and gets the RGB information.

When I use pictures from assets everything works fine but then when I run the app on my iPhone and I import an image from the photo library my code can't analyze pictures that were taken directly with the camera of my iPhone or pictures that are screenshots.

On the other hand, if I send the same picture per WhatsApp and then I download the photo my code can analyze the picture. If I download an image from google images it also works fine.

I have the problem only with pictures that were generated specifically with my iPhone.

Is there something that I'm missing? Formats or something?

Thank you!!

Pablo

**UPDATE**
Could it be that the pictures taken with my iPhone are taken in .HEIC/.HEIF format? Maybe what I need is to convert the pictures to JPG format. Is it HEIC format compatible with UIImage?

Comment: Could you post some code? Maybe enough to duplicate the issue?

Comment: Uff it's a lot of code and I'm using a library called ColorKit. There is no bug in the app. This is what happens; there is an extension that extract the dominant colors of an UIImage and it works like this; image.dominantColors(). This gets a color palette with 8 colors. It works fine but it can't analyze the pictures that were taken with my iPhone. I could share some code but it would be very messy. https://github.com/Boris-Em/ColorKit this is the link of the kit that I'm using. Thanks for answering :)